# as3 Redraw stage in the middle of a loop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a coloring book app built in Flash Pro CS6. I add the shapes to be colored to an object called "coloringBook" with the following code:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= colorable.totalFrames; i ++) {
    shape = new (getDefinitionByName(pattern) as Class)();
    shape.gotoAndStop(i + 1);
    coloringBook.addChild(shape);
    shape.x = Math.abs(gWidth - dWidth)/2;
    shape.y = Math.abs(gHeight - dHeight)/2;
    if (i < colorable.totalFrames) {shape.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, colorColorable);}
}
```

While the code works extremely well, I was hoping to add some polish to the app by showing the user each shape being added to the stage. I can add pauses (e.g. sleep timers) to the code but the app just goes blank until all the timers have completed and shows the finished compilation of shapes. Any guidance on coding would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try just creating one shape per frame using enter_frame. Maybe something like this:

```
var currentIndex:int = 0;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);

private function enterFrameHandler(e:Event):void 
{
    shape = new (getDefinitionByName(pattern) as Class)();
    shape.gotoAndStop(currentIndex + 1);
    coloringBook.addChild(shape);
    shape.x = Math.abs(gWidth - dWidth)/2;
    shape.y = Math.abs(gHeight - dHeight)/2;
    if (currentIndex < colorable.totalFrames) 
    {
        shape.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, colorColorable);
    }
    else 
    {
        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
    }

    currentIndex++;
}
```

Comment: A most elegant solution. Thank you!